# Two-sample Kolmogorov–Smirnov test using scipy.stats.kstest

Tags: python, scipy, kolmogorov-smirnov

I want to use scipy.stats.kstest to test for performing a two-sample Kolmogorov–Smirnov, that is, testing whether two columns (samples)of data to test whether the underlying poplation distribution function is different. Can kstest do this?

My problem is that I could only find in the documentation how to use kstest for comparing a given sample to a known distribution such as normal, t, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a dedicated function [ks_2samp](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ks_2samp.html) which targets your use case.

> This is a two-sided test for the null hypothesis that 2 independent samples are drawn from the same continuous distribution.